# How decision function of Logistic Regression on scikit-learn works?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

I am trying to understand how this function works and the mathematics behind it. Does `decision_function()` in scikitlearn give us log odds? The function return values ranging from minus infinity to infinity and it seems like 0 is the threshold for prediction when we are using `decision_function()` whereas the threshold is 0.5 when we are using `predict_proba()`. This is exactly the relationship between probability and log odds [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/role-of-log-odds-in-logistic-regression/).

I couldn't see anything about that in the documentation but the function behaves like log-likelihood I think. am I right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Decision function is nothing but the value of ([as you can see in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f14af688b7e77ecb6df9dfee93ec39b6c0334b86/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L380))

```
f(x) = <w, x> + b
```

where predict proba is ([as you can see in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L1637))

```
p(x) = exp(f(x)) / [exp(f(x)) + exp(-f(x))] = 1 / (1 + exp(-2x))
```

which up to a constant under exp, is just a regular sigmoid function.

Consequently, the corresponding threshold points will be 0 for f(x), and 0.5 for p(x), since

```
exp(0) / [exp(0) + exp(-0)] = 1 / 2 = 0.5
```

So how do you interpret the decision function? It is essentially 2 times the logit of the probability modeled by LR model. (The "2 times" comes from just a trick scikit-learn uses to always be able to use softmax instead of manually doing sigmoid, which is unfortunate).